# sbt- ManagedStyle.Maven

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Im trying to push  jars from sbt to our local maven repo. I use SBT-0.11.3

I followed the instructions on the github wiki.
I have a build.scala under my project dir with

```
import sbt._
import Key._

object MyBuild extends Build{
    override def managedStyle = ManagedStyle.Maven
   lazy val publishTo = "internal" at "http://playground:9049/archiva/repository/internal/"
}
```

but when I do sbt .I get an error  "not found:ManagedStyle" . How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `managedStyle` method and the `ManagedStyle` object exist only in sbt 0.7.

In sbt 0.10+ you have instead a `SettingKey` named `publishMavenStyle`. For example, in a simple `build.sbt` you write

```
publishMavenStyle := true
```

In a [full build file](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Full-Def), you need to include that in the project's settings.

---

The same goes for your `publishTo` entry—that is a setting, it doesn't make sense to write that at the top level of the build file. Try to stick to the [simple build file format](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Basic-Def).

Comment: @0___ Thanks.. This works.   This  http://www.scala-sbt.org/using_sonatype.html  has an example